# File not found using wamp

Tags: php, apache, web, wamp

I changed the port to 8080 on wamp in the httpd.conf file and it works  using localhost:8080. However, I don't seem to be able to open any file in the wwww-folder, not even the index.php which supposedly is running when using the url `localhost:8080`

> localhost:8080/index gives me

```
Not Found

The requested URL /index was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 8080
```

> Has the path changed? How do I look this up?

Comment: `/index` is not the same as `/index.php`. apache will only use DefaultDocument if you request a DIRECTORY for the url, e.g. `example.com/somedir/`. it's not going to (by default) try various file extensions to see if something matches, so for `example.com/index`, it's going to look for a file (or dir) whose name is EXACTLY `index`, and `index.php` is not going to be matched/used.

Comment: Tried both, no difference

Answer (score 0):

In httpd.conf, you have to change both lines "Listen" and "ServerName" to change the port 80 to 8080.

Comment: I did that, I changed all the lines to 8080.. but it still doesn't work, no other files found. phpadmin works as it should etc